# MongoDB Atlas cluster connection error while running my app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've connected my app with Mongo DB database but when running my app I'm getting this error below,also I confirmed that my username and password are correct, I've seen some questions here like this before but nothing helped me, any help or guidance?

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:800:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:339:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port\app.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'codie-shard-00-00.lcuzy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'codie-shard-00-01.lcuzy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'codie-shard-00-02.lcuzy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any firewall or proxy?

Comment: I have a VPN app I use it to access Mongo DB because it's been blocked from my country I guess. without VPN it wouldn't open.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not whitelisted your IP address on MongoDB Atlas cluster,

follow below and whitelist

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/whitelist-connection-ip-address/